# Header - Footer Bug when i am trying to load them in other HTML files

Tags: html, css

I have an issue and i really dont know how to solve it because of my lack of knowledge( i am a begginer) . Well let me explain you. I am building a blogspot, so i have a header and a footer files which I want to get loaded in every .html files in the project. In order to achieve that I used a script which I found in stack overflow.

The script works fine but I have some minor issues with it. But before continue, let me paste my index.html and header.html and my css files to understand better. This is my index.html file which includes the script.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>The Spooky Side</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Front Page">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="articles-box.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="``header-footer-style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Anton|Dosis|Montserrat|Nosifer&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#header-id").load("header.html");
$("#footer-id").load("footer.html");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header-cl" id="header-id"></div>
<div class="footer-cl" id="footer-id"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the header.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>The Spooky Side</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Header Page">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Anton|Dosis|Montserrat|Nosifer&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="header-footer-style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header-cl" id="header-id">
<a class="header-company-name" href="">The Spooky Side</a>
<a class="header-content" id="about1" href="">About</a>
<a class="header-content" href="../blog/blog.html">Blog</a>
<a class="header-content" href="">Contact</a>
</div>
</body>
```

And finally this is my css file.

```
/*H E A D E R */
.header-cl{
display:flex;
grid-column:1/-1;
background-color: white;
}
.header-company-name{
font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
color:black;
font-size: 2em;
padding-top:17px;
padding-left:30px;
text-decoration:none;
transition-duration: 1.2s;
}
.header-content{
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
color:black;
font-size: 1.6em;
text-decoration:none;
padding: 20px;
transition-duration: 0.7s;

/*^^^space between buttons^^^*/
}
/*F O O T E R */
.footer-cl {width : 100%;grid-column:1/-1;background-color: 
black;color:white;
}
.footer-company-name {
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.4em;
padding-top:20px
}
.footer-content{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin:0px;

}
.footer-anchors{
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
color:white;
font-size: 1em;
text-decoration:none;
}
/*HOVERS DAMN*/
.header-content:hover{
color: #FF0000;
}
.footer-anchors:hover {
color: #510000;
}
.header-company-name:hover{
color:#FF0000;
}
/*I D S */
#about1{
margin-left: auto;
}
/*space between blog's name and other options */
```

And now which is the issue. I am going to post three screenshot. When I run the header.html I got this result which is the right one,(I dont post the footer.html because is the same with the header)which is looks like this.
[header.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1058I.png)

But when I run the index.html in the Atom it looks like this.
[index.html run in Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gujZZ.png)

And finally when I run my code in google chrome it looks like this[Index HTML run in google chrome[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISPSK.png)

As you can see this is my problem. In google the header and the footer are not displayed,and i really dont know why. But in the atom the index.html displays the header but without the correct form, and finally in the header.html when I run it its correct. Anyone have idea why this happening or how can I fix that?

[how folder looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etxn2.png)

Comment: Where are header.html and footer.html located when you upload them to your blog? It's possible that the path is not resolving for these two files: `$("#header-id").load("header.html");
$("#footer-id").load("footer.html");`. Does yourblogurl.com/header.html and yourblogurl.com/footer.html load properly? Do you see any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: All my files are in the same folder. I dont see any javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to load a fragment (just the contents of `#header-id` from header.html into `#header-id` on index.html)
Try this:

```
$("#header-id").load("header.html #header-id");
```

https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments